# C# Содержимое txt-файла в List<T> LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Как грамотно считать строки с вещественными числами из txt-файла в List? Использую этот код:

```
            var list = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\file.txt")
.Select(l => l.Split(' ').Select(decimal.Parse).ToList()).ToList();
```

Но в итоге имею List<<List>

Comment: А как выглядит содержимое txt файла - это мы сами должны догадаться да? Ну а так - первый Select заменить на SelectMany

Comment: 0,5655
0,1215
-1,5252
1,1652

Comment: Это не в коментах писать надо, а править вопрос - "такое то содержимое файла, такой то код, такой то результат, а надо бы такой"

Comment: Ниже уже ответили, причем без лишних вопросов, ответ на которые можно найти чисто логически посмотрев в коде на символ сплита.

Comment: Ну мало ли что ответили. Я в первом коменте тоже ответил без лишних вопросов. Но вопросы должны быть ясными и понятными, чтобы не пришлось играть в логические игры. Правила есть правила. Как ответили, так могли не ответить и закрыть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```cs
var list = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\file.txt")
    .SelectMany(l => l.Split(' ').Select(decimal.Parse))
    .ToList();
```

Метод `SelectMany` позволяет создавать плоскую структуру, если у вас есть вложенные массивы/коллекции (`List<List<decimal>>`).

Comment: `ReadAllLines` => `ReadLines` здесь уместнее.